# Even though LibreOffice Writer is the default program for opening .doc MS Word still opens

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, file-association

Writer opens the file normally, but a really annoying pop-up, owned by a `winword.exe` (MS Word process), appears.

One that says that Word isn't the default program for modifying files. It has a "Don't show this message again" checkbox, but it doesn't do anything.

And another window also made by winword.exe that says:

> "MS Word can't be closed because there is a pop-up window opened"

Go figure.

File type is associated to Writer and I don't really know why MS Word keeps opening... Couldn't find something similar on the internet.

Edit 1: By the way, I don't have a license for it, so when I enter the application it closes because I refuse to buy the license. Is there anything on the application's files, like a config file or a registry that can turn this off.

Comment: *"When you're inside the Word Options screen, select the General tab from the vertical menu on the left, then move over to the right pane. On the right pane, scroll down to Startup options and uncheck the box associated with 'Tell me if Microsoft Word isn't the default program for viewing and editing documents'."* [link](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-word-isnt-your-default-program-for-viewing-and-editing-docs/)

Comment: @Jeeped unfortunately I can't access word since I don't have a license and it will close immediately after I refuse to buy one. Thank you for the information though.

Comment: Find someone who has an identical **licensed** version and examine the registry hive before and after changing the setting. You should be able to export the registry setting to run on your computer.

Comment: Since, apparently,  you don't use MS Word, just uninstall it.